# How to use Emacs auto-complete/snippets?

Tags: emacs, configuration, autocomplete, code-snippets, emacs24

I've been using the [emacs-live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) and it is amazing!

I just can't figure out how to use the autocomplete/snippets, the suggestions pop up, you can cycle through the options, but how do you select an option.

I've tried numinous things to get it to apply the selection, nothing seems to work, it's driving me crazy.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please show parts of your config that you've setup for name completion...

Comment: I believe you tried obvious TAB, ENTER, SPACE

Comment: @OlegPavliv Yes, unfortunately with little success.

Comment: @AlexOtt here is the config https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live/blob/master/packs/live/clojure-pack/config/auto-complete-conf.el  and here is the lib https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live/tree/master/packs/live/clojure-pack/lib/auto-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the problem by pulling the latest version of the config. Not sure what I changed or was changed but it is working now.

Digging around I found a [manual](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live/blob/master/packs/live/clojure-pack/lib/auto-complete/doc/manual.txt) for the plugin with this:

```
### Summary ###

Completion will be started by inserting characters. After completion is started,
operations in the following table will be enabled temporarily. After completion
is finished, these operations will be disabled.

| Key       | Command     | Description               |
|-----------|-------------|---------------------------|
| TAB, C-i  | ac-expand   | Completion by TAB         |    
| RET, C-m  | ac-complete | Completion by RET         |
| down, M-n | ac-next     | Select next candidate     |
| up, M-p   | ac-previous | Select previous candidate |
| C-?, f1   | ac-help     | Show buffer help          |

To stop completion, simply use `C-g`.
```